# Migrating report data from Splunk Server to DSE Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, splunk

I am looking to migrate the reports from Splunk Server(reports after data modelling in Splunk) into DSE Cassandra in Cloud. 
Is it necessary to use Hunk to connect to cassandra?
I want to do a one time dump first and then real time archival from Splunk to Cassandra.
What would be the best option for migration, using API or are there tools/connectors available to do it easier?

thanks in advance!